# PHP String expertise

Tags: php, regex

We written code as. PHP exercise expertise advice needed . Input will be read from custom input which can be provided anything

```
<?php

$Regex_Pattern = '/.t/'; //Do not delete '/'. Replace __________ with your regex. 

$T = intval(fgets(STDIN));
while($T-->0){

    $Test_String = fgets(STDIN);

    if(preg_match($Regex_Pattern, $Test_String, $output_array)){
        print ("true\n");
    } else {
        print ("false\n");
    }
    if(strlen($Regex_Pattern) == 0){
        print ("Warning : Empty regular expression.\n"); 
    }
    if(strlen($Regex_Pattern) > 27){
        print ("Warning : Length of regular expression greater than 25 characters.\n"); 
    }
}
?>
```

We need output as -

```
Input (stdin)
1
jacket
```

Your Output (stdout)
false

Expected Output
true

second expected output is

```
Input (stdin)
3
axe
hat
camera
```

Your Output (stdout)
false
false
false

Expected Output
false
true
false

Input (stdin) 5 hat book camera boombox tv

Your Output (stdout) true false false false false

Expected Output true true false false false

Comment: your assert is not valid. you have dot on the left, but not on the right in

Comment: @AshishJindal You are getting an assertion error with the strings you are comparing.

Comment: Fix your concept function to return the expected string.

Comment: `resultset` is not a table. It's the set of results you're getting from your query. You're getting the error because you don't understand what a *resultset* is - you should be asking your teacher for help if you don't understand your assignment. As to your second issue, it belongs in a different question - this is a *question and answer* site, nota *list of several questions  in one post* site. You may want to spend some time in the [help] to learn how the site works.

Comment: Also, the title of both your posted assignments say *MSSQL*, which is Microsoft SQL. That's not the same as *MySQL*, which is a product owned by Oracle and what you used as a tag.